# Iframe loaded site can access the parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

I am trying to use parameter values and pass these on to an iframe loaded site with javascript. These sites can have multiple styles so I need some kind of switch. I wanted to use parameter but for some reason it cant read the parameter if the site is loaded in the iframe.

```
somesite.com?style=black
```

So is this possible?

If have use the code below to get the values from the url

```
    var urlParams = {};
    (function(){
        var match,
            pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
            search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
            decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
            query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

        while (match = search.exec(query))
           urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an typo in the code. To solve my issue I had to use top.window.location...

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with this? If I `console.log(urlParams)` in the iframe, I get the expected `{ style : "black" }`. Are your iframe and the embedding page hosted on the same domain?